# How to have a fact have multiple values in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am wondering how I can make a fact have multiple values for example:

```
answer(1-100, 'yes').
answer(100-700, 'no).
```

For 1-100 it would be yes and 100-700 it would be no.  Writing thousands of facts would be too time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for [`between/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=between/3):

```
answer( N , yes ) :- between(   1 , 100 < N ).
answer( N , no  ) :- between( 101 , 700 , N ).
```

Because life is too short to repeat the same thing over and over and over.

Comment: Seeing the docs, should the arguments be in a different order? `between(1, 100, N)` ?